# How read multiple files with different schema in Talend?

Tags: schema, talend

Which component to use for reading multiple input files with different schema in talend.

Comment: there is no such component which can read multiple files with different schema

Comment: Can you tell us what are you actually planning to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the subscription version and is called *Dynamic Schemas*. See more for example in [this blog post](https://de.talend.com/blog/2016/03/11/how-to-operationalize-meta-data-in-talend-with-dynamic-schemas/):

> The usage of dynamic schemas can save on maintenance and development in the data management layer. Dynamics schemas can also be used to create tables or files that can be imported as persisted meta-date schemas.

Alternatively, there is a way which can be seen in [this blog post](http://bekwam.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-schemas-in-talend-open-studio.html). I won't copy the contents here since it is a bit old and long post.